# How safe is it to use jQuery 2.0 beta with the latest jQuery Mobile 1.3?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm exploring jQuery Mobile so what I'm doing is not anywhere near production.

Q: Is it ok to use jQuery 2.0 with jQuery Mobile or should I just stick with 1.8.2 like they say to do on the [download page](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)?

Comment: stick to Jquery 1.8.2 with JQM 1.3.0 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience it is safe. I am using jQuery 2.0.0b1 with jQuery Mobile 1.3 and currently I didn't find a problem.

Basically 2.0 is 1.9 but without support for IE 6 and 7. And lets be honest you don't need them for jQuery Mobile. And 1.9 is only a cleaner, slimmer, modern-API upgrade from jQuery 1.8.

On the other hand, like Omar told you in his comment, stick to jQ 1.8.3. Higher version will not provide you with faster or better code execution. They will only learn you to abandon all that deprecated code like bind, live, delegate  .... and so on.

**EDIT :**

I forgot, if you want to use version 2.0 you will need to learn to bind your events with a function **on**. This is very important because 90 % of jQuery Mobile examples use **live** or **bind** for event binding.

Comment: I'm gonna go home and drink milk past the expiration date tonight.

Comment: Hmmm... It didn't seem to work.  I got Cannot read property 'jQuery2002000281277904286980630.5034210172016174' of undefined.

Comment: jquery 2.0 final is out and is not compatible with jqm 1.3.1 for me. Got error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined` line 10313 (sic) of jqm 1.3.1. Seem to be about getting theme for panel.